# How to implement 2 or more triggers on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mariadb, mariasql

Hello this is my structure for `tbl_patient`:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_patient
(
    id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idPatient varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
    namePatient varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    age int NOT NULL,
    birthDate date,
    gender varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    status varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    address varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    work varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    phone varchar(15) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

I want to put 2 triggers on `tbl_patient`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER patientTrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_patient
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.idPatient = CONCAT("PAS-",COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id)+1 from tbl_patient),1));

CREATE TRIGGER ageTrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_pasien
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.age = YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(birthDate);
```

But I got some error with :

> 1235 - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

How can I implement that 2 triggers on my table?

Comment: What the heck are you trying to do here?  `(SELECT MAX(id)+1 from tbl_patient)` -- That is almost exactly what `AUTO_INCREMENT` does.  But it does it in an unsafe way.

Comment: Since `age` continues to change; compute it in `SELECT`; do _not_ store it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [computed columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/) instead:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_patient
(
    id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idPatient varchar(15) AS (CONCAT("PAS-", id)),
    namePatient varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    age int AS (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(birthDate)),
    birthDate date,
    gender varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    status varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    address varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    work varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    phone varchar(15) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

Remarks:

1) Note that your code to calculate age is not correct, for example (2015-12-31 and 2016-01-01).

Better way to calcualte age:

```
SELECT YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthDate) - 
       (DATE_FORMAT(birthDate, '%m%d') > DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d')) AS age
```

2)

```
CREATE TRIGGER patientTrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_patient
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.idPatient = CONCAT("PAS-",COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id)+1 from tbl_patient),1));
```

is  poor solution when multiple concurrent INSERTs occur.

---

**EDIT**

Using triggers you have update age when user update `birthDate` (yes it may happen).

Other possible solution is to simply create view.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_patient
AS 
SELECT `id`,  `namePatient`, `birthDate`,
       `gender`, `status`, `address`, `work`, `phone`,
  CONCAT("PAS-", id) AS `idPatient`,
  YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthDate) - 
       (DATE_FORMAT(birthDate, '%m%d') > DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d')) AS `age`
FROM `tbl_patient`
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c6a4/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: I got this : #1901 - Function or expression is not allowed for column 'age'

Comment: @ElraGhifary That's odd. From doc `User-defined functions and stored functions cannot be used (built-in functions can be used) `

Comment: If I put your formula to calculate age into trigger, 'unknown birthDate column in field list'. I would solve this age by create one a new trigger, and namePatient just like you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Try to merge body of both triggers into single one, something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER patientTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_patient FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.idPatient =  CONCAT("PAS-",COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id)+1 from tbl_patient),1)); 
    SET NEW.age = YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(birthDate);
END
```

Comment: I got this in PHPMyAdmin: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3